# terraform performing force replacement when no changes made

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform-aws-modules

I am building a aws vpc with the following module:

```
module "vpc" {
  source = "terraform-aws-modules/vpc/aws"
  version = "4.0.1"
  name = "k8-vpc"
  cidr = var.vpc_cidr

  azs             = var.availability_zones
  private_subnets = var.private_subnets
  public_subnets  = var.public_subnets

  enable_nat_gateway = true
  single_nat_gateway = true
  create_igw = true
  map_public_ip_on_launch = true

  tags = {
    Terraform = "true"
    Environment = "dev"
  }
}
```

and create an instance with this code:

```
#Bastion
resource "aws_instance" "bastion" {
  depends_on = [module.vpc]
  ami           = var.ami_id
  instance_type = "t2.micro"
  subnet_id = module.vpc.public_subnets[0]
  associate_public_ip_address = "true"
  security_groups = [aws_security_group.allow_ssh.id]
  key_name          =   aws_key_pair.k8_ssh.key_name
  tags = {
    Name = "Bastion"
  }
}
```

When performing an apply directly after another apply (no changes made, in theory nothing to do) I am getting the following message

```
      ~ secondary_private_ips                = [] -> (known after apply)
      ~ security_groups                      = [ # forces replacement
          + "sg-0cbcca0d4fef3ecf2",
        ]
        tags                                 = {
            "Name" = "Bastion"}
...
Plan: 1 to add, 0 to change, 1 to destroy.
```

It appears the security group is triggering a rebuild.  I have had depends_on aws_security_group.allow_ssh, and module.vpc and neither changes the behavior...
I have verified when an instance gets rebuild, the same security group is on the old instance and new instance in the console.  Any ideas how to prevent a needless rebuild?

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `vpc_security_group_ids`, instead of `security_groups`. The latter is only for default VPC and EC2-Classic.